# .NET Core RuntimeIdentifiers still required?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a packager project that modified the .csproj of the main project file to make sure the `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` are properly set.

This project was in .NET Core 2.0, likely it was .NET Core 1.something when I first wrote that code.

However, now that I am rewriting it, I noticed it just works fine, if I don't set the `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` at all. Or in other words, `dotnet publish --runtime` seems to work just fine.

As I can recall from various google search, `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` was needed, because we needed the packages to be available in `dotnet restore` time.

My theory is, `dotnet publish` now (.NET Core 2.1) restores the projects with the proper `RuntimeIdentifiers` so we don't need to set them anymore. Or I should still set it, because otherwise I can encounter unexpected issues?

Comment: In the meantime I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) in official docs. This may lead towards the answer. "Starting with .NET Core 2.0, you don't have to run dotnet restore because it's run implicitly by all commands that require a restore to occur, such as dotnet new, dotnet build and dotnet run."

Comment: I've published standalone .NET Core 2.0 console apps that target both .NET Core and .NET 4.6.1, and as far as I can tell the `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` element doesn't do anything, i.e. I can publish/run the app without specifying runtime(s) in the `.csproj` file.  Still haven't found whether or not it officially _is_ required or not. I do specify framework when running `dotnet publish`, though.